# LESS ignore inheritance, render child block as a global

Tags: css, less

Is there a way I can ignore inheritance in a less mixin ?

```
.foo{
  #someblock > .render() ;
}

#someblock {
   @top:10px;
   @left:40px;
  .render() {
    .makeabsolute(@top,@left);
  }
}

.makeabsolute(@top,@left) {
  position:absolute;
  top:@top;
  left:@left;
  .gt-ie8 {
   //IE8 CSS using @top @left
  }
}
```

This will render as i.e. the gt-ie8 will be rendered inside the foo block.

```
.foo {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:40px;
    .gt-ie8 {
       //IE8 CSS
    }
}
```

Can we have the less code render as this ?  i.e. the gt-ie8 is rendered outside, as a "global" ?
This should be at the level of .makeabsolute.

```
.foo {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:40px;
}


.gt-ie8 .foo{
    //IE8 CSS using @top @left
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `&` *after* .gt-ie8:

```
.makeabsolute(@top, @left) {
    position: absolute;
    top:      @top;
    left:     @left;
    .gt-ie8 & {
        /* IE8 CSS using @top @left */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it there a documentation around this ?

Comment: https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-language-Nesting#appender. Less4j wiki is the most detailed LESS documentation for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like:

#### LESS

```
.foo{
  .makeabsolute(10px,40px);
}

.makeabsolute(@top,@left) {
  position:absolute;
  top:@top;
  left:@left;
  & .gt-ie8 {
   //IE8 CSS using @top @left
  }
}
```

#### Output CSS

```
.foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 40px;
}
.foo .gt-ie8 {
  //IE8 CSS using @top @left
}
```

Comment: But I need .gt-ie8  is at the parent level.